Wave Equation with Non Homogenous Boundary Conditions and Force
With a wave equation like this
$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \frac{\partial y^2}{\partial x^2}+\beta x$$
Where
\begin{gathered}
y(0, t)=A \\
y(L, t)=B \\
y(x, 0)=f(x) \neq 0 \\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x, 0)=g(x) \neq 0
\end{gathered}
In order to solve this, are you first supposed to handle the extra force or the non-homogenous boundary conditions? To work with the extra force I understand you must assume that the PDE is separable, and create a reference function to "cancel" out the $\beta x$. However, the PDE is not actually separable yet due to the nonhomogenous boundary conditions correct? So we would first have to assume an equilibrium solution $u_e$, such that
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u_e}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u_e}{\partial x^2}+\beta x
$$
So this would give us
$$
u_e=\frac{-\beta x^3}{6 c^3}+c_1 x+c_2
$$
And we could now solve for our constants with our boundary conditions? Does this step also take care of the reference function to eliminate $\beta x$ or have I messed up in my process?
Thank you all!

You are in the right track. The most important thing is to "homogenize" the boundary conditions, but in this case you can also cancel the external force in one fell swoop. Choose $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $u_e(0)=A$ and $u_e(L)=B$. Then, the solution to the wave equation will be given by $y(x,t)=u_e(x)+v(x,t)$, where $v(x,t)$ is the solution to
\begin{align}
v_{tt}&=c^2v_{xx} \
v(0,t)&=0 \
v(L,t)&=0 \
v(x,0)&=f(x)-u_e(x) \
v_t(x,0)&=g(x)
\end{align}

Thank you! I am a bit confused how we can get rid of the external force with $u_e$. So here I find $u_e = \frac{\beta x(L-x)(L+x)}{6 c^3}+\frac{x(B-A)}{L}+A$.
When I tried to solve it I said $v(x, t)=y(x, t)-u_e(x)$. So I could solve $v_{t t}=c^2 v_{x x}$ as you mentioned. I solve for $v(x,t)$ which would require me taking the partials of $u_e$ and $y(x,t)$ which would return $\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\beta}{c^3} x$ so is this still valid? But it would just be much easier to solve it in terms of $v$ as $v_{t t}=c^2 v_{x x}$ instead of $y$?

Forget $y$! Now you have to solve a new problem (the equation $v_{tt}=c^2v_{xx}$ with the conditions listed in my comment). Once you have the solution to this new problem, the solution to the original problem will be $y(x,t)=u_e(x)+v(x,t)$.

Perhaps this Maple Worksheet helps.
